# Can't install python libraries, common solutions aren't working

Tags: python, cmd

I know this is a common problem and I've tried the solutions, but I'm stuck.

I want to install gazpacho, I do `pip3 install <library-name>` which works, but in my IDE I still get the `No module named 'gazpacho'` error. This happens with any library, not just gazpacho.

I've tried `python -m pip3 install <library-name>` but I get the error `command not found: python`? I'm guessing it has something to do with pip3 installing to a different place from where Python is looking? How should I solve this? I'm new to using command prompt.

I'm using iOS 12.6, M1 chip, PyCharm IDE (free version).

Comment: Perhaps you have the `python3` command? Are you using a "virtual environment" in your IDE?

Comment: That gives en error ```No module named pip3```, and doing ```python3``` with ```pip``` works, but still gives the same error in IDE. I don't think I'm using a virtual environment, I accepted all default settings when installing PyCharm

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyCharm there is a terminal(cmd) too. Just install it using a built-in terminal. Because in PyCharm with default settings every project has a virtual environment.